# How Do Unmerged Paths in Index Occur

Tags: git

In the "git status" man page, there is a table that describes the meaning of the XY status code when the short-format or the porcelain format is used. Specifically, the table is:

```
X          Y     Meaning
-------------------------------------------------
          [MD]   not updated
M        [ MD]   updated in index
A        [ MD]   added to index
D         [ M]   deleted from index
R        [ MD]   renamed in index
C        [ MD]   copied in index
[MARC]           index and work tree matches
[ MARC]     M    work tree changed since index
[ MARC]     D    deleted in work tree
-------------------------------------------------
D           D    unmerged, both deleted
A           U    unmerged, added by us
U           D    unmerged, deleted by them
U           A    unmerged, added by them
D           U    unmerged, deleted by us
A           A    unmerged, both added
U           U    unmerged, both modified
-------------------------------------------------
?           ?    untracked
!           !    ignored
-------------------------------------------------
```

My question is, how exactly does one get an unmerged item in the index to occur (the X-column)?

My understanding of an unmerged item is when a merge was attempted but there a conflict between the sources of the merge, the resulting file is considered "unmerged". How does such an item make it into the index if merging is only done between a tree and the working copy.

Answer (score 1):

I think I may have discovered the answer to my own question. In the git-status man page where it discusses the short-format, there are 2 lines that I previously missed:

"For paths with merge conflicts, X and Y show the modification states of each side of the merge. For paths that do not have merge conflicts, X shows the status of the index, and Y shows the status of the work tree."

So, it seems, the meaning of the 2 columns changes depending on whether a merge conflict was detected or not. The follow-on to this is that it is indeed not possible to have unmerged items in the index.

I don't know how I missed those lines, but, I did.

Comment: To clarify one point: conflicts are stored *in the index* (in the file itself) but are not *staged*.  They are stored as higher (non-0) stage entries.

Comment: See also the [new Git 2.31 (Q1 2021) documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65766809/6309)